# Subscribing SNS topic with HTTP End point in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, aws-sdk, amazon-sns

The question is not regarding subscribing to SNS Topic via HTTP endpoint. I was successfully able to configure and also confirm the subscription. Also, I am able to receive messages at the endpoint.

The requirement is to have another subscriber of the topic in nodejs backend app. I tweaked the code in [this article](https://stackabuse.com/publishing-and-subscribing-to-aws-sns-messages-with-node-js/) for setting up the application, however couldn't manage to do so.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const credentials = new AWS.SharedIniFileCredentials({ profile: '<profile-name>' });
const sns = new AWS.SNS({ credentials: credentials, region: 'eu-central-1' });

let params = {
    Protocol: 'HTTP',
    TopicArn: 'arn:aws:sns:eu-central-1:TOPIC:NAME',
    Endpoint: 'http://mockbin.org/bin/bin-id'
};

sns.subscribe(params, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

The response is

```
{
  ResponseMetadata: { RequestId: '0af83f58-c562-592f-b493-65fef627ac28' },
  SubscriptionArn: 'pending confirmation'
}
```

However, in the console, i see this endpoint as confirmed

[image]

Can someone suggest here.

Comment: See this question for a more complete code example for how to set this up: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55636322/how-to-subscribe-a-http-endpoint-to-sns-in-node-js. Simply calling subscribe is not enough to set up and receive messages to a HTTP endpoint.